# crash forçando reload no app

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, react-navigation, native

Durante uma operação de pagamento com SDK (Cielo e SafraPay), nosso app está sofrendo um reload aparentemente em casos aleatórios ou esporádicos.

Não consegui reproduzir em ambiente Dev, mas o nosso log txt mostra que no momento em que o nosso app deveria receber os dados de pagamento da SDK, por algum motivo o app chamou Stack inicial de abertura do app, e acaba gerando uma rotina de não confirmação do pagamento por causa disso.

- Segue meu package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "src",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint *.js **/*.js",
        "init-app": "rm -rf node_modules/ && git submodule init && git submodule update && yarn",
    
        "build-android-debug": "yarn && npx jetify && cd android && gradlew clean && gradlew assembleStoneRelease && cd ..",
        "build-android-mobile": "yarn && npx jetify && cd android && gradlew clean && gradlew bundleMobileRelease && cd ..",
        "build-android-qa-mobile": "yarn && npx jetify && cd android && gradlew clean && gradlew assembleMobileRelease && cd ..",
        "build-android-dtef": "yarn && npx jetify && cd android && gradlew clean && gradlew assembleDtefRelease && cd ..",
        "build-android-cielo": "yarn && npx jetify && cd android && gradlew clean && gradlew assembleCieloRelease && cd ..",
        "build-android-stone": "yarn && npx jetify && cd android && gradlew clean && gradlew assembleStoneRelease && cd ..",
        "build-android-rede": "yarn && npx jetify && cd android && gradlew clean && gradlew assembleRedeRelease && cd ..",
        "build-android-getnet": "yarn && npx jetify && cd android && gradlew clean && gradlew assembleGetnetRelease && cd ..",
        "build-android-safra": "yarn && npx jetify && cd android && gradlew clean && gradlew assembleSafraRelease && cd ..",
    
        "dev-dtef": "yarn clean && react-native run-android --verbose --variant=dtefDebug --port=9988",
        "dev-stone": "yarn clean && react-native run-android --verbose --variant=stoneDebug --port=9988",
        "dev-cielo": "yarn clean && react-native run-android --verbose --variant=cieloDebug --appIdSuffix=cielo --port=9988",
        "dev-rede": "yarn clean && react-native run-android --verbose --variant=redeDebug --appIdSuffix=rede --port=9988",
        "dev-getnet": "yarn clean && react-native run-android --verbose --variant=getnetDebug --appIdSuffix=getnet --port=9988",
        "dev-safra": "yarn clean && react-native run-android --verbose --variant=safraDebug --appIdSuffix=safra --port=9988",
        "dev-mobile": "yarn clean && react-native run-android --verbose --variant=mobileDebug --appIdSuffix=mobile --port=9988",
        "clean": "cd android && ./gradlew clean --warning-mode=all && cd ..",
        "signer": "cd android/app && apksigner sign --ks keystore.jks --out app-signed.apk app-padrao-universal-release.apk",
        "signer-cielo": "cd android/app && apksigner sign --ks keystore.jks --out app-cielo-signed.apk app-cielo-universal-release.apk",
        "git-push-dtef": "cd linx-postos-smartpos-dtef && git push origin HEAD:develop && cd ..",
        "git-update": "git fetch && git pull",
        "git-submodule-update": "git submodule sync && git submodule update --init --recursive --remote"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.8.5",
        "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^2.9.0",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.7.0",
        "apisauce": "^1.0.2",
        "dayjs": "^1.9.7",
        "esrever": "^0.2.0",
        "gzip-js": "^0.3.2",
        "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "lottie-react-native": "^3.5.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "pg": "^8.7.3",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "16.9.0",
        "react-native": "0.61.4",
        "react-native-base64": "^0.1.0",
        "react-native-camera": "^2.0.2",
        "react-native-debounce-input": "^1.0.5",
        "react-native-device-info": "^7.4.0",
        "react-native-dotenv": "^2.4.0",
        "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.0",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
        "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
        "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.0.6",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
        "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.11",
        "react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.9",
        "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
        "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
        "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^4.0.1",
        "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
        "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
        "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
        "redux": "^4.0.4",
        "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
        "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
        "reduxsauce": "^1.1.1",
        "remask": "^0.1.0-alpha.5",
        "runes": "^0.4.3",
        "seamless-immutable": "^7.1.4",
        "string-length": "^4.0.2",
        "styled-components": "^4.4.1",
        "uuid": "^3.3.2",
        "vanilla-masker": "^1.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.2",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
        "eslint": "^6.6.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.5.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.8.1",
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
        "react-native-dotenv": "^2.4.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
      },
      "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
      }
    }
```

-Segue meu Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.smartposv2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.getnet.posdigital.service.POSDIGITAL" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="titan.extperm.USB_SET" tools:node="remove"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" tools:node="remove"/>


    <application
      android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
      tools:replace="android:name"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          <category android:name="safra" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <data android:host="retornopagamento" android:scheme="AppIntegrador" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <data android:host="retornocancelamento" android:scheme="AppIntegrador" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <data android:host="response" android:scheme="order" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

- Segue trecho do cód nativo responsável por capturar os dados de pagamento:

  callbackTransacaoIntegracao = new Gerenciador.AutomationInterface() {

  ```
  @Override
  public void processaSaidaTransacao(final SaidaTransacao saidaTransacao) {
    UtilsFormat formatCallBack = new UtilsFormat();
    DefaultReturn retorno = new DefaultReturn();
    String method = "initPayment -> processaSaidaTransacao";
    String initLogCallback = REACT_CLASS + " - " + method + " -> ";
    try {

      if (saidaTransacao == null)
        return;

      formatCallBack.sendLogEvent(initLogCallback + "PAGAMENTO REALIZADO - callback processaSaidaTransacao",
          reactContext);
      int resultadoTransacao = saidaTransacao.obtemResultadoTransacao();
      formatCallBack.sendLogEvent(initLogCallback + "obtemResultadoTransacao: " + resultadoTransacao, reactContext);

      if (resultadoTransacao == ReturnCodes.RESULT_APROVADA) {
        JSONObject objReturn;
        try {
          objReturn = UtilsFormat.returnTransactionData(saidaTransacao, transactionType);
          formatCallBack.sendLogEvent(
              initLogCallback + "TRANSACAO APROVADA -> returnTransactionData: " + objReturn.toString(),
              reactContext);

          promise.resolve(objReturn.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          formatCallBack.sendLogEvent(initLogCallback + "ERROR returnTransactionData: " + e.getMessage(),
              reactContext);
          retorno.setFail("" + e.getMessage());
          promise.resolve(retorno.toJSON());
        }

      } else {
        formatCallBack.sendLogEvent(
            initLogCallback + "TRANSACAO REPROVADA -> obtemResultadoTransacao: " + resultadoTransacao,
            reactContext);
        retorno.setFail("" + resultadoTransacao);
        promise.resolve(retorno.toJSON());
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      formatCallBack.sendLogEvent(initLogCallback + "ERROR - FATAL EXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage(), reactContext);

      retorno.setFail(
          "Erro ao processar dados de pagamento. Não foi possível confirmar status/dados de pagamento. MSF004");
      promise.resolve(retorno.toJSON());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void processaException(Exception e) {
    format.sendLogEvent(initLog + "processaException: " + e.getMessage(), reactContext);
  }
  ```

  };

OBS:

- No listener criado para capturar os dados de pagamento add diversas validações e try-catch's para tentar capturar possíveis erros de tratamento, mas ao lançar isso em produção no nosso arquivo de log em txt não ficou registrado nenhum dos logs de erros visto no código acima.
- em nenhum momento consegui simular esse erro, por isso, estou tentando abranger todas as possibilidades: ambiente, rede e etc

LOGS DO APP:
Linha mostrando o inicio do pagamento ->
28/09/2022 12:03:58.993 - Cielo -> initPayment:{"ValorTransacao":10000,"primaryCode":"1000","secondaryCode":"1","Parcelas":2}

Linha mostrando a função que é chamada na abertura do app ->
28/09/2022 12:04:48.210 - Loading -> resetLoading: "CALL resetLoading"

Existe uma diff de tempo entre essas linhas nos mostrando que o erro ocorre no momento em que os dados deveriam ser retornados ao nosso app no listernet enviado acima.

Se o nosso app tivesse recebido os dados antes do reload teríamos esse log no mínimo:
"PAGAMENTO REALIZADO". Oque nos dá evidência de que o reload ocorreu antes do callback da SDK ser chamado.

---

O que poderia gerar esse tipo de erro?
Por que ele é esporádico e não ocorre em todos os equipamentos?
Como posso evitar esse tipo de problema?
Existe alguma forma de logar em txt toda vez que o nosso for fechado?

Att.

Comment: Creio que é o mesmo problema dessa postagem: [App está sofrendo um reload de forma aleatória em produção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/566470/70) - Para evitar duplicação de instruções, o espaço de comentários está desativado aqui. As orientações foram passadas na postagem original, que pode ser editada para reavaliação.